# How to get the price of an spl token relative to solana?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token-program, spl

The thing is that I need to calculate the price of a tokan in sol or in usd. I would use one of the publicly available APIs, such as birdeye or jupiter, but they do not display the price of tokens that have not yet launched by open_time. I have all the information about the token such as metadata and liquidity pools from raydium.[image]